# Mysql full text search exact match not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have a products table, that contains these data:

```
         name           |
-------------------------   
Nokia X 4GB Nokia X 3G  |
Nokia X 4GB 3G          | 
Nokia XL 4GB Nokia X 3G | 
Nokia XL 4GB Nokia X 3G |
Nokia Asha 512          |
Nokia Lumia 925         |
Nokia Asha 306 2GB      |
....
```

And then when i run this query:

```
 SELECT name, 
 MATCH(name) AGAINST('+Nokia +X +4GB +3G' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) AS rank 
 FROM products as p 
 ORDER BY rank DESC limit 4;
```

It should return the first 4 results in the table, but i see it returns

```
Nokia Asha 309 A00008390
Nokia Asha 306 2GB
```

Anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default word length for MySQL full text index is 4 characters. You should try changing it to 1 character. To do this, add the following setting to your my.ini file in the `[mysqld]` section:

```
ft_min_word_len=1
```

Then restart MySQL server, and then drop then recreate the full text index to rebuild it.

Comment: Looks like `REPAIR TABLE products QUICK` will be better than drop and recreate the index, right ?

Comment: Yes, that would do the job, too, I believe.